# To locate the deprecated API

Tags: android

I got this activity. ReportActivity.java
After i recompile, here is the error.

> uses or overrides a deprecated API.
>   Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details

However, the activity is with a green tick on top right corner with no warning,

My question is,
1. where is the deprecated method
2. How to eliminate the warning during compilation

```
package tk.myessentialoils.a16personalities;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class ReportActivity extends CustomMenu {
    private TextView mTextMessage;
    String path ="portraits";
    LinearLayout parent;
    int[] result = new int[4];
    String typeName;
    List<String[]> rows;
    Spinner spinner;
    TextView textView,desc;
    BottomNavigationView navView;
    int navigator;
    ImageView imageView;
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                mTextMessage.scrollTo(0,0);
                mTextMessage.setText(Html.fromHtml(getStringResourceByName(typeName+"2")));
                navigator=R.id.navigation_home;
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                mTextMessage.scrollTo(0,0);
                mTextMessage.setText(Html.fromHtml(getStringResourceByName(typeName+"1")));
                navigator=R.id.navigation_dashboard;
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                mTextMessage.scrollTo(0,0);
                mTextMessage.setText(Html.fromHtml(getStringResourceByName(typeName+"3")));
                navigator=R.id.navigation_notifications;
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

public void setImageParticular(){
    rows = new ArrayList<>();
    CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(this, "16p.csv");
    try {
        rows = csvReader.readCSV();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int i = check();
    //int i = Arrays.asList(rows).indexOf(typeName.toUpperCase());
        TextView job = findViewById(R.id.textView11);
        job.setText(String.valueOf(rows.get(i)[1]));
        desc = findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        String a = (rows.get(i)[2]+"\n"+(rows.get(i)[3]));
        //String a = String.valueOf(rows.get(i)[2]+"\n"+String.valueOf(rows.get(i)[3]));
        desc.setText(a);

    textView.setText(typeName.toUpperCase());
    mTextMessage.setText(Html.fromHtml(getStringResourceByName(typeName+"2")));

}

public int check (){

    int index = -1;
    for (int i=0;i<rows.size();i++) {
        if (rows.get(i)[0].equals(typeName.toUpperCase())) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    Log.d("index",""+index);
    return index;

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_report);
    navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    parent = findViewById(R.id.linearChart);
    spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    mTextMessage = findViewById(R.id.description);
    mTextMessage.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    typeName = intent.getStringExtra("type");
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView10);
    textView.setText(typeName.toUpperCase());
    mTextMessage.setText(Html.fromHtml(getStringResourceByName(typeName+"2")));
    //Log.d("TYPE",typeName);
    setImage(typeName);

    result = intent.getIntArrayExtra("arrays");
    Log.d("Array", "arr: " + Arrays.toString(result));

    if (result!=null){
        drawMyChart();
    }

    setImageParticular();


    boolean result = intent.getBooleanExtra("result",false);
    //Toast.makeText(this,typeName,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (result) {
        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        desc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else {
        addItemsOnSpinner();
    }
}

public void addItemsOnSpinner() {

    final ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
    AssetManager assetManager = getApplicationContext().getAssets();

    try {
        for (String file : Objects.requireNonNull(assetManager.list(path))) {
            if (file.endsWith(".jpg"))
                items.add(file.replaceAll(".jpg$", "").toUpperCase());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(list));
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            typeName = items.get(position).toLowerCase();
            setImage(items.get(position).toLowerCase());
            setImageParticular();
            navView.setSelectedItemId(navigator);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
}

public void setImage(String typeName){
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = getAssets().open(path+"/"+typeName+".jpg");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}

private String getStringResourceByName(String aString) {
    String packageName = getPackageName();
    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(aString, "string", packageName);
    return getString(resId);
}

public void drawMyChart(){

    String[]a= new String[]{
            check(result[0], "E", "I"),
            check(result[1], "N", "S"),
            check(result[2], "T", "F"),
            check(result[3], "P", "J")};

    for (int i = 0; i< result.length; i++){

        double percent = (result[i] - 8) * 100 >> 5;
        //double percent = (result[i]-8)*100/32;
        float f = (float) percent/100;

        if(result[i]>24){
            createBarChart(f,a[i]);
        }else{
            createBarChart(1-f,a[i]);
        }

        Log.d("PERCENT",""+percent+","+f);

    }

}

public String check(int set,String a, String b){
    if (set>24){
        return a;
    }else{
        return b;
    }
}

public void createBarChart(float percent, String a){

    View custom = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_bar_chart, null);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 100);
    lp.weight = percent;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 100);
    lp2.weight = 1-percent;

    LinearLayout leftLL = custom.findViewById(R.id.leftLL);
    leftLL.setLayoutParams(lp);
    LinearLayout rightLL = custom.findViewById(R.id.rightLL);
    rightLL.setLayoutParams(lp2);

    TextView tvLeft = custom.findViewById(R.id.left_percentage);
    String b = String.format("%.0f", (double) percent *100)+"%";
    tvLeft.setText(b);

    TextView textView= custom.findViewById(R.id.leftLetter);
    textView.setText(a);

    parent.addView(custom);

}
}
```

Comment: I think if you run the LINT (I can't remember where the option is unfortunately) it will give you a report which will include what classes and what lines there are deprecated APIs within the project. It also might not be in your project, it could be a library you are importing potentially

Comment: Is it alright to ignore it?

Comment: Yes and no, your app will still work using the deprecated APIs at the moment, that being the key point. If at some point you need to update something, whatever you update could end up removing those deprecated APIs which usually happens after some time so then your app won't compile and you will still need to try and find where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

```
Html.fromHtml("") //It is deprecated.
```

Refrance: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html#fromHtml(java.lang.String)

Solution:

```
HtmlCompat.fromHtml("", HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
```